# Elasticsearch Join

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elk

I have two indices. One indices "indications" which have some set of values.
Other is "projects". In this indices, I will add indications value like `" indication = oncology"`.
Now I want to show all indications. Which I can do using terms aggregations. But my issue is that I also want to show count of project in which that indication is used .
So for that, I need to write join query.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Expected result example:

```
[{name:"onclogogy",projectCount:"12"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** have joins in Elasticsearch. What you can do is store indication name in `project` index and then apply the term aggregation on `project` index. That basically will get you the different `indications` from all the project documents and count of each indication.

Something of the sort:

```
GET /project/_search
{
    "query": {},
    "aggs": {
        "indcation":{
            "terms": {
                "field": "indication_name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch does not supports joins. That's the whole point of having NoSQL that you keep the data as **denormalised** as you can. Make the documents more and more self sufficient.
There are some ways with which you can add some sort of relationship b/w your data. [This](https://rockset.com/blog/can-i-do-sql-style-joins-in-elasticsearch/) is a nice blog on it.

Comment: Thank you @dravit  for your response.
Actually I can use this query, But it is stratifying not my requirement.
If any indications are not available in project then i want to show 0 or black value beside that indication name.

Comment: For that, you can make 2 separate queries. First one on `indication` index to get all the indication names (use aggregations). You can save these names in a set, say `all_indications`. Then the second query on `project` index to get the indications and their count (as done above). Store the indication names from the result in another set, say `indications_present_in_projects`. If `all_indications - indications_present_in_project` is non-empty set, you set the count for these indications `0` or `black`.
It sounds a bit lengthy but everything has it's pros and cons. Otherwise just use some SQL.